# Menu Items disabled after creating all the views in an EditorPart

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am creating an EditorPart consisting of three views (typical tree, info, detail layout). I must add, that the tree-view is a

> org.eclipse.ui.part.Page

I am using the IHandlerService to connect my Handlers to the commands, which are defined in my plugin.xml. The menu itself is created by using the menuContribution, which looks like:

```
<menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:**ThePage**?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="id.of.the.edit.command"
               icon="platform:/plugin/company.resources/icons/etool16/fancyicon.png"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="activeEditor">
                  <instanceof
                        value="**TheEditorPart**">
                  </instanceof>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
```

The problem is: When **TheEditorPart** is fully created and visible and I right-click on the tree (which is in **ThePage**), the menu items in the context menu are all disabled. Do I click somewhere in the detail part of the editor part or any other part (the toolbar, etc.) *before* I right click the tree, the context menu items are enabled.
Is there anything I can do to make the "**TheEditorPart**" manually active? Or do I miss something in the initialization?

Answer (score 0):

While I was investigating the issue, I stumbled over the little hint within the plugin.xml, which says . I found out, that the editorPart was giving the focus to a non-visible component, which probably lead to giving no focus at all. Changing that and giving the focus to a visible component helped to solve the issue.